# How to rpm from Qt project that is build by qmake?

Tags: qt, installation, binary, rpm

I have developed some project by Qt and now I want to distribute the binary of the projects with rpm?

These project have dependency to Qt(Qt so files) that must be checked before install and if is not existed then copy them to ld search path(e.g. /usr/lib) and some other so file like this.

Now:

1. rpm is capable for doing this?
2. if is capable, how can I do this?

   **Of course, If you see when you want to install qt sdk there is a GUI installer will be run for you on all distribution of Linux.**
3. how can I use this kind of Installer?

Answer (score 1):

rpm just like most package managers can manage package dependencies. It is such a basic feature commented on most rpm tutorials that you might very well start here:

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html

Comment: Thank your answer, but when I make installer on windows, we can copy some file in the some folder that we want (nsis installer) and check existance for version and some dll. Now when I read rpm for this feature that a programming language for advanced mode I can find this. Are you aware from this feature for advanced setting (check existence some file and copy to /usr/local/lib) in rpm?

Comment: @user868372 No, rpm does not do it. RPM requires you to install the packages your application depends on. Most package managers are able to fetch and install the missing packages for you. But your package *never* installs files from other packages.